# How to port this doubles into an NSDecimalNumber?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a some doubles that I want to port into NSDecimalNumber, because I'm getting too bad floating-point arithmetic errors with them.

They are:

```
double one = 0.0000001;
double two = 1000000000.0000001;
```

They are very problematic, but I hope that NSDecimalNumber can help out to get calculations right. I'm not that big math genius, so I wonder how to provide the correct input to this method of NSDecimalNumber.

Let me try:

```
NSDecimalNumber *one = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1 exponent:-7 isNegative:NO];

NSDecimalNumber *two = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:10000000000000001 exponent:-7 isNegative:NO];
```

I feel that's wrong. I could only guess. The documentation does not provide much information on that. But as far as I get it, the "mantissa" is an integer and the exponent tells where the floating point should be, by adding zeros. Probably this is also wrong ;-)

I have seen some code snippets where people just feeded a CGFloat as mantissa and provided a 0 as exponent, but I can only guess what their intention was, so I can't just do it the same way without understanding it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of the class, numbers are represented as `mantissa x 10^exponent`.

So, you are pretty right with your assumptions.

Your number is first of all the `mantissa`. The decimal point is after your number and gets pushed to the right `exponent` times (if the exponent is positive, zeroes will be added as the points stays on the right side). In the end, a minus sign will be put before your number according to the `isNegative` flag.

So for example, if you have `123 * 10 ^ (-3)`, it starts with `123.`, goes over `12.3` and `1.23` to `0.123`, where the decimal point is three digits left as before

Note that this type also has restrictions. The [reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) shows them:

> [...]where mantissa is a decimal integer up to `38 digits long`, and exponent is an integer from `–128` through `127`

Maybe, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) is able to explain the scientific notation of numbers better, which is exactly what you have to use here :-)

Comment: thanks Etan, I think my old school memories come back now. Only that negative exponent thing is not too clear to me. i.e. if my mantissa is 123, and my exp is -3, would I have a number like 0.000123 then?

Comment: 10 ^ -3 is 0.001, not 0.0001, so if your mantissa is 1.23 and your exp is -3 you'd have 0.00123.

Comment: sorry there was indeed some error in my explanation. the decimal point is moved exponent digits to the _right_, not as stated in my original post to the _left_. I have included your 123*10^-3 example into my post., 0.000123 would be 123 * 10^-6 = 12.3 * 10^-5 = 1.23 * 10^-4 = 0.123 * 10^-3 = 0.0123 * 10^-2 = 0.00123 * 10^-1 = 0.000123. Hope that this helped you with your problem.

Comment: Thanks guys, now all this mantissa and exponent stuff seems clear to me. 38 digits for NSDecimalNumber also includes those "fractional" digits, right? So the "worst balanced" number I could have is something like 9999999999999999999.9999999999999999999 * 10^-128 or *10^127? should be enough for my stuff ;)